# Do we have any library to generate entity fields in a class from a table?

Tags: jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa, entity, dao

For generating setters and getters for multiple fields in a class, we have lombok. Similarly, do we have any framework or library to get columns from a table in db and generate it on an entity class? It would be really useful while working with tables with a lot of columns instead of writing each field individually.

Answer (score 0):

Not a library but a function in the IDE.
In Eclipse right-click on a project containing a persistence.xml
and select **JPA-Tools -> Generate Entities from Tables...**